# Python, how to detect a 'right' arrow key to skip some line of codes

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm new to this forum and python, any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to add a if statement under FOR LOOP, as my code shows below, at the moment, my mouse moves to 4 spots before it closes the current web tab, and it repeats this for 10 times.

My question is how to add a if statement ie. if the right arrow key is pressed while the mouse is moving, it skips a few line of codes and goes straight to the last four line of codes?

The current tab is closed and it moves onto the next tab, until it finishes it's 10 cycles.  This new If statement helps to close the browser tab much quicker with human intervention instead of waiting for the whole 8 seconds.

Thank you.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time, pyautogui
import keyboard

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
pg.moveTo(2679, 900)
pg.click()

for i in range (10):
    pg.moveTo(2679, 1620, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(2679, 1923, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(1365, 1875, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(1365, 1572, duration=2)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.keyDown('w')
    pg.keyUp('w')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, however when the right arrow key is pressed it will exit the loop being able to continue the code.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time, pyautogui
import keyboard

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
pg.moveTo(2679, 900)
pg.click()

for i in range (10):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
        break
    pg.moveTo(2679, 1620, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(2679, 1923, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(1365, 1875, duration=2)
    pg.moveTo(1365, 1572, duration=2)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.keyDown('w')
    pg.keyUp('w')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
```

or maybe:

```
for i in range (10):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.keyDown('w')
        pg.keyUp('w')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    else:
        pg.moveTo(2679, 1620, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(2679, 1923, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(1365, 1875, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(1365, 1572, duration=2)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.keyDown('w')
        pg.keyUp('w')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!-------

1: the first answer isn't what I was looking for, as it breaks the loop-------

2: the key isn't detected until the last move to (1365, 1572) is finished, and there is only a half second time window to press the right key, if missed, the  cursor goes onto next journey.

Answer (score 0):

You could use threading to check for the keypress instantly which might save some time.

```
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui as pg
import time, pyautogui
import keyboard

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
pg.moveTo(2679, 900)
pg.click()
pressed = False
StopCheckingForKey = False

def loop_function():
    global pressed, StopCheckingForKey
    for i in range (10):
        pg.moveTo(2679, 1620, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(2679, 1923, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(1365, 1875, duration=2)
        pg.moveTo(1365, 1572, duration=2)
        if pressed == True:
            pressed = False
        else:
            pg.keyDown('ctrl')
            pg.keyDown('w')
            pg.keyUp('w')
            pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    StopCheckingForKey = True

def check_key():
    global pressed, StopCheckingForKey
    while not StopCheckingForKey:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
            pg.keyDown('ctrl')
            pg.keyDown('w')
            pg.keyUp('w')
            pg.keyUp('ctrl')
            pressed = True


t1 = Thread(target=loop_function)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()

t2 = Thread(target=check_key)
t2.setDaemon(True)
t2.start()
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help, really useful. --------------This setup is closer to what I am looking for. As it detects the "right arrow" at any given time and closes the tab. However, the cursor continues it's original path (circles 10 times until it closes the whichever tab it's on, and move onto the next tab), What would be the best way to code it, so once the 'right arrow' key is detected, it closes the current tab, terminates the previous flight path, and starts the movement all over again from the first spot (2679, 1620) for 10 circles? Thank you.